# Oracle Insert Data Into Object Table

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

What is the most per-formant manner to insert data into an object table?

```
 Create Type R_Emp Is Object
    (Emp_Id number, Last_Name varchar(50));

 create type T_Emp is table of R_Emp;
```

Then given an inbound array insert values:

```
V_T_Emp     T_Emp := T_Emp();

For i In 1..p_array.COUNT
Loop
   ..... // Best way to load values
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the data coming from?  Assuming the data is coming from one or more tables

```
SELECT r_emp( emp_id, last_name )
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_t_emp
  FROM table_name
```

If the data is coming from somewhere else, you'll need to tell us where the data is coming from.  If `p_array` and `v_t_emp` are both collections of type `t_emp`, you can just directly assign them

```
v_t_emp := p_array;
```

But if you're just copying the data from one collection to another identically defined collection, there normally wouldn't be any reason to introduce the second collection.

Comment: The data is coming from the array. Eg. V_T_Emp.Extend(1);
    V_T_Emp(i) := p_array(i);

Comment: @MichaelS - What is different about `p_array` and `v_t_emp` that causes you to want to move the data between them?  If they're both instances of `t_emp`, why copy the data in the first place?

Comment: I need to use them further down to join sql on a collection in the where clause.  I am trying to remove the use of global temporary tables for this and just use table objects.

Comment: @MichaelS - But why not use `p_array` in the `WHERE` clause down the line?  I updated my answer with an example of doing a direct copy if the two collections are defined identically but that doesn't seem particularly useful.

Comment: The p_array is being passed in as a type of number table.  I will get a type conversion issue on v_t_emp := p_array;.  I'm also not iterating over each item in the collection and executing sql against the current record.  I don't want to execute the sql statement times the number of extents in the array.  I'm just looping to load the number table into my object table.  Then outside the loop will execute a single sql statement grouping by one of the columns and where the value is in the object table.

Comment: @MichaelS - So then do you have two inbound arrays?  One for the numeric `emp_id` and one for the string `last_name`?

Comment: Yes, there would be a number array and varchar array. In this instance I am just trying to satisfy a particular use case but more over for small arrays where indexing isn't needed I want to being using object tables in lieu of temporary tables.  So, just trying to find the most efficient way to load these various array's into an object table.